# ASP.NET MVC 2 for mobile devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

As far as I can tell the recommended approach for ASP.NET MVC **1** is to use the [Web Application Toolkit for Mobile Web Applications](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile).

Is there any change in the mobile device story for **ASP.NET MVC 2**? Should this toolkit still be used?

Comment: There's a comment there which says it works with a few tweaks. My advice is to try it, but *turn debug mode **off** in Web.config!* With debug mode off, MVC will cache view locations, and I think (but can't prove yet) this changed a bit from MVC 1 to MVC 2. Then load a desktop view, and finally the equivalent mobile view. If that works, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried out the Web Application Toolkit and it works fine. I just used the code which essentially detects the browser and routes to views you define. Very useful and recommended.